# How to display JSON data with `vis.js`

Tags: php, mysql, json, vis.js, vis.js-network

I want to display data from MySQL with `vis.js`.
I get data with JSON, but I am having this error:

> Error: Node must have an id
>
> ```
>   throw new Error("Node must have an id");
>   -------^
> ```

[image]

```js
function tampil()
{
 $.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  cache :false,
  dataType: "json",
  url:"fetch.php",
  success: function(data){
   console.log(data);
   
   var vertex = new vis.DataSet([
       {id:data[0], label:data[1]}
   ]);
   var hubung = new vis.DataSet([
       {from:data[2], to:data[3]}
   ]);
   var myDiv = document.getElementById("media");
   var data = {
    nodes : vertex,
    edges : hubung
   }
   
   var options = {};
   
   var network = new vis.Network(myDiv,data,options);
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vis.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/vis.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <button type="button" onclick="tampil()">proses</button>
 <div id="media" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my server sid like this

Comment: please show what `console.log(data);` outputs so that we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, in JavaScript I've added the following code:

```js
function tampil()
{
 $.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  cache :false,
  dataType: "json",
  url:"nodes.php",
  success: function(data){
   console.log(data);
    
   var vertex = new vis.DataSet();
   var hubung = new vis.DataSet();
   var myDiv = document.getElementById("media");
   var data = {
    nodes : vertex,
    edges : hubung
   }
   
   var options = {};
   
   var network = new vis.Network(myDiv,data,options);
   
   $.getJSON('edges.php', function(edges) {
    hubung.add(edges);
   });
   $.getJSON('nodes.php', function(nodes) {
    vertex.add(nodes);
   });
  }
 });
}
```